# Regular Expression not matching

Tags: java, regex, liferay

I'm trying to create a RegExp to match new passwords (which works), but I only need a last step to make it work 100%.

Here's the RegExp and what it is supossed to:

```
((?=.*(\\d|[\\(\\)\\{\\}\\?!\\$&\\*%\\=\\+_\\-\\.]))(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,})
```

The RegExp says that: Digits **OR** Symbols `(){}?!$&%*=+-.` must be used *-and that's what doesn't work, the OR operator, as **I can insert both numbers and symbols**-*, at least one lowercase, at least one uppercase and a minimum lenght of 8 characters.

I've tried to use the OR operator `|` in several ways, but I can't make it work.

What am I missing? Thank you very much in advance.

Note: I'm using this regular expression within a liferay configuration file for the password policies.

Comment: To my knowledge, the OR operator in regex, like in most other situations, is inclusive, not exclusive, so it'll accept both as being ok. I could very well be wrong on this, not too familiar with regex.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't escape the usual special characters in a character class (inside `[]`). The only special characters there are `]`, `\ `, `-` and `^`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've rewritten your expression slightly, this is what I came up with:

```
String pattern = "^(?=.*[\\d().{}?!$&*%=+_-])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$";
```

This matches any string with

- at least one number *or* special character
- at least one lower-case letter
- at least one upper-case letter
- is at least 8 characters long

Answer (score 3):

You want a XOR logical operation, not a OR.

```
OR is true:
A |  B |  o/p
T |  T |   T
F |  T |   T
T |  F |   T
F |  F |   F

XOR is true:
A |  B | o/p
T |  T |  F
F |  T |  T
T |  F |  T
F |  F |  F
```

[Exclusive Or in Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247167/exclusive-or-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2):

I have to say that, while regex can probably do this, I think it's simpler and safer to use multiple regex tests, something like:

```
boolean containsDigit = Pattern.matches("[0-9]", testString);
boolean containsSymbol = Pattern.matches("[(){}?!$&%*=+.-]", testString);
boolean containsLowercase = Pattern.matches("[a-z]", testString);
boolean containsUppercase = Pattern.matches("[A-Z]", testString);

if(testString.length() >= 8
        && containsLowercase
        && containsUppercase
        && (containsDigit || containsSymbol)
        && !(containsDigit && containsSymbol)) {
    //valid
} else {
    //invalid
}
```

I was using a Java regex pattern a few months ago that was not wildly complex, but it led to a Java bug being revealed. Too many parenthetic clauses seemingly caused trouble, and I had to split the pattern into something simpler.

The above is much more readable than a multi-clause regex pattern, and therefore easier to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 1):

You said,

> I can insert both numbers and symbols

That would be normal with a logical OR operation.  It sounds like what you want is exclusive or (XOR).  I'm afraid I don't know how you do that in regex, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.