# Regex match between two tags or else match everything

Tags: regex

I have a list of email addresses which take various forms:

```
john@smith.com
Angie <angie@aol.com>
"Mark Jones" <mark@jones.com>
```

I'm trying to cut only the email portion from each. Ex: I only want the `angie@aol.com` from the second item in the list.  In other words, I want to match everything between `<` and `>` or match everything if it doesn't exist.

I know this can be done in 2 steps:

1. Capture on `(?<=\<)(.*)(?=\>)`.
2. If there is no match, use the entire text.

But now I'm wondering: Can both steps be reduced into one simple regular expression?

Comment: what language are you using to implement this?

Comment: @scrowler: Visual Basic (work)

Comment: Are you working in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
(?<=\<).*(?=\>)|^[^<]*$
```

`^[^>]*$` will match the entire string, but only if it doesn't contain a `<`. And that's OR'ed (`|`) with what you had.

**Explanation:**

`^` - start of string
`[^<]` - not-`<` character
`[^<]*` - zero or more not-`<` characters
`$` - end of string

Answer (score 1):

You're after an exclusive or operator. [Have a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247167/exclusive-or-in-regular-expression)

`(\<.+\@.+\..+\>)` matches those email addresses in side `<>` only...
`(\<.+\@.+\..+\>)|(.+)` matches everything **instead** of matching the first condition in the OR then skipping the second.

Depending on what language you are using to implement this regex, you might be able to use an inbuilt exclusive or operator. Otherwise, you might need to put a bit of logic in there to use the string if no matches are found. E.g. (pseudo type code):

```
string = 'your data above';
if( regex_finds_match ( '(\<.+\@.+\..+\>)', string ) ) {
    // found match, use the match
    str_to_use = regex_match(es);
} else {
    // didn't find a match:
    str_to_use = string;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could mark 2 answers correct because yours was very helpful and informative.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but your current logic is probably simpler.  Here is what I came up with, email address will always be in the first capturing group:

```
^(?:.*<|)(.*?)(?:>|$)
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/8tKHaYYY4T

Comment: Interesting but I don't quite understand it.  It also isn't working on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?36s24).