# Find files with regex match and different regex not match

Tags: regex, grep

I have three files `foo1.txt`, `foo2.txt` and `foo3.txt`, which contain the following lines

```
# foo1.txt
JOBDONE
```

and

```
# foo2.txt
Execution halted
```

and

```
# foo3.txt
Execution halted
JOBDONE
```

I have been able find the ones with both `JOBDONE` and `Execution halted` using:

```
find ./foo*.txt | xargs grep -l 'Execution halted' | xargs grep -l "JOBDONE"
```

But have not been able to find those files which have `JOBDONE` or `Execution halted` but not both. I have tried:

```
find ./foo*.txt | xargs grep -lv "JOBDONE"  | xargs grep -l "Execution halted"
find ./foo*.txt -exec grep -lv "JOBDONE" {} \;  | xargs grep -l "Execution halted"
```

but have been incorrectly (to my understanding) returning

```
./foo2.txt
./foo3.txt
```

What is wrong with my understanding of how `xargs` and `exec` works with grep and how do I use grep or another portable command to select those logs that have `JOBDONE` but not `Execution halted` or vice versa?

Comment: What you want is an exclusive or (XOR). Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247167/exclusive-or-in-regular-expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `gnu awk` (gnu due to multiple characters in RS)

```
awk -v RS="#-#-#" '/JOBDONE/ && /Execution halted/ {print FILENAME}' foo*
foo3.txt
```

Setting  `RS` to something that is not in the file, it will thread all lines as one.
Then test if the long line has both string, and if yes, print filename

Comment: Nice, +1 for the awk, I am assuming I can negate either condition by a preceeding `!`?

Comment: @mkemp6 Yes you can negate it and also add more condition.