# Regex to find words that start or end with a particular letter

Tags: python, regex

Write a function called `getWords(sentence, letter)` that takes in a sentence and a single letter, and returns a list of the words that start or end with this letter, but not both, regardless of the letter case.

For example:

```
>>> s = "The TART program runs on Tuesdays and Thursdays, but it does not start until next week."
>>> getWords(s, "t")
['The', 'Tuesdays', 'Thursdays', 'but', 'it', 'not', 'start', 'next']
```

My attempt:

```
regex = (r'[\w]*'+letter+r'[\w]*')
return (re.findall(regex,sentence,re.I))
```

My Output:

```
['The', 'TART', 'Tuesdays', 'Thursdays', 'but', 'it', 'not', 'start', 'until', 'next']
```

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247167/exclusive-or-in-regular-expression

Comment: If you have already gotten responses, please do not modify your question in a way that invalidates answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It you want the regex for this, then use:

```
regex = r'\b(#\w*[^#\W]|[^#\W]\w*#)\b'.replace('#', letter)
```

The `replace` is done to avoid the repeated verbose `+letter+`.

So the code looks like this then:

```
import re

def getWords(sentence, letter):
    regex = r'\b(#\w*[^#\W]|[^#\W]\w*#)\b'.replace('#', letter)
    return re.findall(regex, sentence, re.I)

s = "The TART program runs on Tuesdays and Thursdays, but it does not start until next week."
result = getWords(s, "t")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['The', 'Tuesdays', 'Thursdays', 'but', 'it', 'not', 'start', 'next']
```

#### Explanation

I have used `#` as a placeholder for the actual letter, and that will get replaced in the regular expression before it is actually used.

- `\b`: word break
- `\w*`: 0 or more letters (or underscores)
- `[^#\W]`: a letter that is not `#` (the given letter)
- `|`: logical OR. The left side matches words that start with the letter, but don't end with it, and the right side matches the opposite case.

Comment: Thank you very much I learned about .format() in one above answer and .replace() from yours. My question is what is the purpose of : [^#\W]|[^#\W]

Comment: `[^#\W]` : Does it relate to one character or one word in the string?

Comment: It relates to one character as there is no `+` or `*` following it. It says: "match one character that is not my letter and is not a non-letter either", which comes down to "match a letter that is different from my letter". The OR operator `|` extends further than that: it applies to the part between parentheses (or the whole pattern if there would have been none), so it says it should match either `#\w*[^#\W]` or `[^#\W]\w*#`.

Answer (score 5):

`\b` detects word breaks.  Verbose mode allows multi-line regexs and comments.  Note that `[^\W]` is the same as `\w`, but to match `\w` except a certain letter, you need `[^\W{letter}]`.

```
import re

def getWords(s,t):
    pattern = r'''(?ix)           # ignore case, verbose mode
                  \b{letter}      # start with letter
                  \w*             # zero or more additional word characters
                  [^{letter}\W]\b # ends with a word character that isn't letter
                  |               #    OR
                  \b[^{letter}\W] # does not start with a non-word character or letter
                  \w*             # zero or more additional word characters
                  {letter}\b      # ends with letter
                  '''.format(letter=t)
    return re.findall(pattern,s)

s = "The TART program runs on Tuesdays and Thursdays, but it does not start until next week."
print(getWords(s,'t'))
```

Output:

```
['The', 'Tuesdays', 'Thursdays', 'but', 'it', 'not', 'start', 'next']
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, it does solve my issue. I learned a new thing with .format. But I am lost in the expression, I understood \b{letter}, \w*. But what does i signifies in (?i) and why did you use \W in OR block.

Comment: @AsheemChhetri Added comments.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this is much easy with the `startswith()` and `endswith()` method.

```
def getWords(s, letter):
    return ([word for word in mystring.split() if (word.lower().startswith('t') or 
                word.lower().endswith('t')) and not 
                    (word.lower().startswith('t') and word.lower().endswith('t'))])

mystring = "The TART program runs on Tuesdays and Thursdays, but it does not start until next week."
print(getWords(mystring, 't'))
```

Output

```
['The', 'Tuesdays', 'Thursdays,', 'but', 'it', 'not', 'start', 'next']
```

---

> Update (using regular expression)

```
import re
result1 = re.findall(r'\b[t]\w+|\w+[t]\b', mystring, re.I)
result2 = re.findall(r'\b[t]\w+[t]\b', mystring, re.I)
print([x for x in result1 if x not in result2])
```

**Explanation**

Regular expression `\b[t]\w+` and `\w+[t]\b` finds words that start and ends with letter `t` and `\b[t]\w+[t]\b` finds words that both starts and ends with letter `t`.

After generating two lists of words, just take the intersection of those two lists.

Comment: This changes the case of the result.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I request to reconsider downvoting!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using regex for this? Just check the first and last character.

```
def getWords(s, letter):
    words = s.split()
    return [a for a,b in ((word, set(word.lower()[::len(word)-1])) for word in words) if letter in b and len(b)==2]
```

Comment: I am asked to use regex only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the builtin `startswith` and `endswith` functions.

```
>>> string = "The TART program runs on Tuesdays and Thursdays, but it does not start until next week."
>>> [i for i in string.split() if i.lower().startswith('t') or i.lower().endswith('t')]
['The', 'TART', 'Tuesdays', 'Thursdays,', 'but', 'it', 'not', 'start', 'next']
```